# How to set the Open GLES effect on android Camera?

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-emulator

I want to set the Android Camera with the OpenGLES effect.
But i dont know how to set that.
So is there any Demo Example to that Uses OpenGLES and Android Camera ??
Or Help me in how to make it possible to done some normal effect in Android Camera with OpenGLES support.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic effects can be done with [Camera.Parameters.setColorEffect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setColorEffect%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: see my question Jaa-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629833/add-filter-to-camera-output-at-runtime