# Android - Camera and OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

i need to create a camera class which draw animation from openGL ES. image which captured from camera will be surfaceholder for image animation from OpenGL.

its like navigation on Wikitude or Layar.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have same question. But not getting any reply till today. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976032/how-to-set-the-open-gles-effect-on-android-camera and also this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962520/how-to-set-the-open-gles2-0-to-work-with-the-android-camera  If yout got any proper answer then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: me too. what happen with stackoverflow tags android >_<

Comment: you can try this link @iDroid Explorer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629182/android-draw-opengl-image-on-top-of-camera

Comment: This may help: http://nhenze.net/?p=154 This example is better, though a bit offtrack, but does solve your problem : http://code.google.com/p/armsk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start from make a surfaceView and add a callback to it. [this example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid) maybe can help solve your problem

John,