# Android - Draw OpenGL image on top of Camera

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

I want to draw an animation 2D/3D with OpenGL ES, which draws on top of camera,
can anyone provide me the example. I need this very much.

thanks for helping!

Comment: I have never coded android but this is the second result in Google when searching for *android open gl camera*: http://digitalbreed.com/2009/android-render-opengl-on-top-of-camera-preview

Answer (score 2):

SurfaceView will not work like regular view. So what you should do is you should wrap the SurfaceView with frame or relative layout. Because both of them supports z-ordering. Create a class extending View and add the above logic in to it. Make an instance of this class in your layout XML. Now this relative or frame layout is ready to expose the drawing..

The following one is very useful. Have a look...

https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry/